# Running Selenide with Selenium Grid?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid, selenide

In Selenide, creating a driver is simply using:

```
`open(Link);`
```

along with some system properties setting the webdriver and browser to use:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "K:/chromedriver.exe");
System.setProperty("selenide.browser", "Chrome");
```

In Selenium however, you must declare drivers and set capabilities.

How would I configure my test cases in Selenide to run parallel on the Selenium Grid?

Does anyone have a sample set-up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could created common RemoteWebDriver and just tell Selenide to use it by WebDriverRunner.setWebDriver(driver);

After using your own driver - Selenide won't be responsible for closing it, so it's your responsibility now)

```
String urlToRemoteWD = "http://some.url.to.remote/wd/hub";
RemoteWebDriver driver =new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(urlToRemoteWD),DesiredCapabilities.firefox());
WebDriverRunner.setWebDriver(driver);
```

and close `WebDriverRunner.closeWebDriver();`

Comment: Okay, I will give that a try. If I set that up in each of my test cases, and set up my testng.xml to run tests parallel, is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: I think that's it, everything else should run as usual. Again, just don't forget to close browsers if you used browser creation by pure Selenide before.
And set correct browser capabilities =)

Answer (score 1):

To run tests on Selenium Grid use `selenide.remote` system property. This way you don't need to manage WebDriver manually.

I use gradle and add this property for `test` task if it exists in an environmental variable:

```
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    def seleniumServerUrl = System.getenv("SELENIDE_REMOTE")
    if (seleniumServerUrl) {
        systemProperty("selenide.remote", seleniumServerUrl)
    }
}
```

or you can add a property in a command line: `-Dselenide.remote=http://localhost:5678/wd/hub` as suggested in https://selenide.org/faq.html